# Float an ImageView next to multiple TextView elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to float an image to the right of two text views.  Something like: [image: Floated image]

"My Title" represents one TextView with a specific font style and the lorem ipsum text represents another TextView.  I would prefer the lorem ipsum text to flow around the image, without hard coding new lines.

Is this possible and if so, any ideas for how to do it?  I would ideally like to handle the layout in an xml layout file if possible, but can use code if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this class - https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to simply use a WebView and put your text and images in HTML. Android doesn't have any sort of flow layout.